# Why the variables count doesn't get incremented by 1 for every corresponding number?

Tags: python, list, function, methods

```
def countTemps(temperature):
```

The function takes "temperature" list as argument, and it should find and return the positive, negative and zero numbers.

```
    temperature=(0, 1, 5, -3, 4, 15, 6, -2, 8, -5, 10, 0, -4, 0, 7)

    posCount, negCount, zeroCount = 0, 0, 0

    integers = 0
```

For each temperature the corresponding variable's count should increment by 1.

```
    for integers in temperature:

        if integers < 0:

            negCount += 1

            return temperature

        elif integers > 0:

            posCount += 1

            return temperature

        else:

            return temperature

            zeroCount += 1

            return temperature

print("Number of Positive: ",posCount)
print("Number of Negative: ",negCount)
print("Number of Zeros: ", zeroCount)
```

But, why is their output Zero instead of the correct counting?

Comment: Is there a question you would like to ask?

Comment: Yes, I can't find the mistake. Why the count of each variable doesn't get returned in the function?

Comment: Please update your question and include which result you expect to get and which result you actually get and I will try to answer it. Here's a guide on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The function will exit as soon as it hits the first `return temperature` line.

Answer (score 0):

The function `countTemps` exits as soon at it reaches a `return` statement. In your case that means the loop will increase `zeroCount` once and then stop. The changes to variables made inside a function aren't visible outside of the function though, so `zeroCount` won't be 1 after the function terminates.

If you remove all `return` statements and instead make sure to return all your counts *after* the loop, you can catch those outside of the function.

```
def countTemps(temperature):
    ....
    for integers in temperature:
        ....
    return (posCount, negCount, zeroCount)
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the counts somewhere else, you can just move the `print` statements inside of the function but after the loop, and avoid using `return`.